# Error in printing JSON contents

Tags: php, arrays, json

Following is a JSON response I got from the server. I'm trying to print the contents using foreach loop in a PHP page. But I couldn't do so. Can anyone have a look at the code & tell me where did I go wrong??

When I printed contents of `$value['nice']` using `vardump()`, I got the following output in the screen.

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'key1' => string 'A' (length=2)
      'key2' => string 'B' (length=4)
      'key3' => string 'C' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'key1' => string 'D' (length=4)
      'key2' => string 'E' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'key1' => string 'F' (length=3)
      'key2' => string 'G' (length=3)
```

So `$value['nice']` is an array which contains array data.
I used the following foreach loop for iteration. But output I got was 'No Data found'. Only the else part of the if-else statement inside the foreach loop is getting executed. Where did I go wrong??

```
                            foreach($value['nice'] as $key1=>$value1)
                            {
                                if(array_key_exists('key1',$value['nice']))
                                {
                                    $show=$value1["key1"];
                                    echo $show;
                                }
                                else
                                {                                        
                                    echo 'No Data Found!';
                                }

                            }
```

Expected Output:

```
A B C
D E
F G
```

Comment: You should check for `key1` not in `$value['nice']` but in `$value1`

Comment: I tried that. Same result. Wrong output. @u_mulder

Comment: Side note: you can ```echo $value1["key1"]``` directly, there is no need to use a variable here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pointing to the current array, while you want the inner one :

```
if(array_key_exists('key1',$value1))
```